# Haskell cannot match type

Tags: haskell

I'm still a beginner with Haskell and I've this piece of code, but ghc doesn't compile and gives me an error

This is the code:

```
data QT a = C a | Q (QT a) (QT a) (QT a) (QT a) deriving (Show)

moltiply :: QT a -> Int -> QT a
moltiply (C a) x = (C (a * x))
moltiply (Q a b c d) x = Q (moltiply a x) (moltiply b x) (moltiply c x) (moltiply d x)
```

And this is the error I get:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘a’ with actual type ‘Int’
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for multiply :: QT a -> Int -> QT a
          at file.hs:12:15
    Relevant bindings include
      a :: a (bound at file.hs:13:15)
      multiply :: QT a -> Int -> QT a
        (bound at file.hs:13:1)
    In the second argument of ‘(*)’, namely ‘x’
    In the first argument of ‘C’, namely ‘(a * x)’
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you write

```
moltiply :: QT a -> Int -> QT a
```

you're telling GHC that this function will work with any type `a` inside your `QT` type, but then you write

```
moltiply (C a) x = (C (a * x))
```

and try to multiply the value `a` which can be of any type with an `Int`. This does not seem right does it?

You can fix this in two ways:

1. Ask GHCi what the most general type of `moltiply` is by removing the type signature and loading the file in GHCi:

   ```
   λ> :t moltiply
   moltiply :: Num a => QT a -> a -> QT a
   ```

   Then you can add this type signature to your source file (good for documentation) or leave the function without a type signature.
2. Stick to `Int` by saying that `moltiply` requires `QT` to contain an `Int`:

   ```
   moltiply :: QT Int -> Int -> QT Int
   ```

Answer (score 2):

The only thing you can multiply by an `Int` using `*` is another `Int`. You need to either restrict your type signature to

```
moltiply :: QT Int -> Int -> QT Int
```

or generalize it to

```
moltiply :: Num a => QT a -> a -> QT a
```

or change the implementation to something like

```
moltiply :: (Num a, Integral b) => QT a -> b -> QT a
moltiply (C a) x = (C (a * fromIntegral x))
moltiply (Q a b c d) x = Q (moltiply a x) (moltiply b x) (moltiply c x) (moltiply d x)
```